# How to resolve the javascript error of CKEditor in IE 11

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My asp.net website uses CKEditor 3.5.3. While it works fine on all other browsers, it gives the following error in IE 11:

```
JavaScript runtime error: NotSupportedError

N=F.$.createEvent('KeyEvents')
```

It appears that for IE 11, we have to use CKEditor version 4.3.4. I am wondering whether there is any fix for just the javascript error, since I don't want to upgrade for now.

My main reluctance for the upgrade, apart from the time involved is that, the latest version doesn't have a dll to be used by asp.net applications which the older versions had.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exact issue, and I don't want to upgrade the whole CKE control, so I managed to fix the issue by adjusting the code in the compressed ckeditor.js to check for IE 11 or above.

Pretty much, the `createEvent('KeyEvents')` is no longer valid for IE11 and it needs to be changed to `createEvent('Events')`.

Following the call to createEvent, there will be an `initKeyEvent('keypress', ....)` method call which also needs to be adjusted to call `initEvent('keypress', ....)` for IE11+.

After putting in the necessary conditional statements to detect IE11 (using dojo in the example below), the adjusted CKE JS is as follows:

```
O=G.$.createEvent(dojo.render.html.ie >= 11 ? 'Events' : 'KeyEvents');
if(dojo.render.html.ie >= 11)
    O.initEvent('keypress',true,true,F.$,false,false,false,false,0,32);
else
    O.initKeyEvent('keypress',true,true,F.$,false,false,false,false,0,32);
```

The above JS code may be different from yours, but the example still applies to the invalid use of the synthetic events for IE11.

Answer (score 0):

They released new version 3.6.6.2

### Try it: http://download.cksource.com/CKEditor/CKEditor.NET/CKEditor.NET%203.6.6.2/ckeditor_aspnet_3.6.6.2.zip

You don't need to update the DLL, just download and replace the old ckeditor folder (you may want to keep the config.js file if you changed it before) with the new ones.

Download link:
http://download.cksource.com/CKEditor/CKEditor/CKEditor%204.4.3/ckeditor_4.4.3_full.zip

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these responses worked for me. Instead I added:
"X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"  to my _Layout.cshtml file. This resolved the error, although I'm sure there's some technical debt incurred by doing this. This goes in a meta tag. No markdown for that tag.