# XPages unable to paste image in Rich Text field

Tags: xpages, richtextbox

I am working on an XPage application with a rich text field on a page. **In the application, I am unable to paste the image (even plain text) in rich text field.**

The application is deployed in two servers (master copy on one server, and a replica copy on another server). Everything is working fine in master copy of database (on master server), but in the replica copy of the application, paste images and texts is not working.

When trying to insert image through 'Insert Image' tool bar button of rich text control, popup gets opened but nothing works in the popup (neither upload button, not ok, cancel or close buttons works here)
['Insert Image' Popup screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcXmL.jpg)

Configuration settings of both servers are almost identical. **As per my knowledge, the only difference is that, in maser server, session based authentication mode is configured, and in the server having replica copy, basic authentication mode is configured.**

I referred the debugger of the browser (internet explorer 11) to identify the problem, and found that the code is getting stuck during execution [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TupzX.jpg)

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Look into dev tools of browser, probably some GET/POST request fails.

Comment: Thanks @Frantisek Kossuth for the guidance. I tried to identify the problem and found that there is some type of java script error. But not able to understand the reason of error. Please refer updated question for the screen of error. Thanks...

Comment: seems to be related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142816/how-to-resolve-the-javascript-error-of-ckeditor-in-ie-11
are both servers the same version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the reason of the problem.

The problem is because the required fix pack has not been installed on the server.

Application on master server uses DOJO 1.9.7, so everything is working fine here.

Application on another server (replica copy of master) uses DOJO 1.8.3, which is the cause of the problem. Because of older version of DOJO, controls are not being rendered properly.

Thanks all